# PHPSeclib SysRq code?

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

PHPseclib resource has a page: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/keys.html

```
Key String
Ctrl + C    "\x03"
F1  "\x1BOP"
F2  "\x1BOQ"
F3  "\x1BOR"
F4  "\x1BOS"
```

however its very very lacking

Does anyone know the code for SysRq or Alt+PrtScn?

Answer (score 0):

[Per Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-ASCII-code-for-the-print-screen-key-in-a-keyboard/answer/Vivek-Nagarajan-1), PrtScn doesn't have an ANSI escape code like the above do. It also looks like PrtScn [isn't a supported terminal mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-8) in SSH.

Have you seen an SSH client where that is possible in?

Also, my laptop (a Windows laptop) doesn't have SysRq. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Alt+PrtScn = SysRq---------------https://stefanoprenna.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/foto_010411_0011.jpg